# Simpleaudio doesn't install: legacy-install-failure

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install Simpleaudio on Windows in  order to use Pydub but I get a legacy-install-failure in the cmd. Here is the complete output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install simpleaudio
Collecting simpleaudio
  Using cached simpleaudio-1.0.4.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for simpleaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: simpleaudio
  Running setup.py install for simpleaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for simpleaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio
      copying simpleaudio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio
      copying simpleaudio\shiny.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio
      copying simpleaudio\functionchecks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      copying simpleaudio\test_audio\c.wav -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      copying simpleaudio\test_audio\e.wav -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      copying simpleaudio\test_audio\g.wav -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      copying simpleaudio\test_audio\left_right.wav -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      copying simpleaudio\test_audio\notes_2_16_44.wav -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\simpleaudio\test_audio
      running build_ext
      building 'simpleaudio._simpleaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simpleaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Am I supposed to download and install 'Build Tools for Visual Studio'? If so, is there a specific place it should be installed in?
Thank you.

Comment: `Am I supposed to download and install 'Build Tools for Visual Studio` yes `If so, is there a specific place it should be installed in?` no, any place, it just needs to be installed. you should generally just believe error messages that are that specific. Or at least look them up first.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/simpleaudio/#files There're binary wheels for Python 3.7 and 3.8.

Comment: I have tried to install the wheels but they are not supported on my platform ```>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> from platform import python_version
>>> print("Current Python Version-", python_version())
Current Python Version- 3.9.1``` Is there a solution for this? Thank you.